# calling fopen in GAS windows

Tags: windows, assembly, dll, ld, gnu-assembler

I'm not going to use gcc here. This is pure `as` assembly with `ld`. 32-bit code. I've been able to do a whole lot except use any `c` functions. I know that in windows, `fopen` and `fwrite` are actually functions with an underscore but I am still not able to retrieve these from coredll.dll or msvcrt.dll. Can anyone tell me what dll these are found in? I can load a library through `LoadLibrary(thedll.dll)`

Comment: So you're writing 32-bit code?  In 64-bit code, symbols don't get leading underscores.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention this is 32-bit. i beg to differ on the underscores. i have masm 64 code that uses popen and i am not able to do so unless i use _popen

Comment: You're on Windows.  POSIX `popen` doesn't exist, the C function name for the Microsoft version is `_popen` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170).  In 32-bit code, the asm symbol name would be `__popen` (two underscores).  Also, see how MSVC compiles `int foo(){return 0;}`  - https://godbolt.org/z/7bK4zeqTT for x64 vs. x86 with vs. without a leading underscore.

Comment: you might be right about `popen`. i am strictly using `fopen` here. i found the function and it is not `__fopen` or `_fopen`, but rather `fopen`

Comment: Yes, exactly, in 64-bit Windows code, the asm symbol names match the C names, so `fopen` and `_popen`.  In 32-bit Windows code, an underscore is prepended regardless of the original name, so `_fopen` and `__popen`.  (For most other OSes, the name-mangling convention is the same for both bitnesses.)

Answer (score 0):

the dll that `fopen` belongs to is located in `ucrtbase.dll`. in masm 64, this is defined as `%includelib ucrt.lib` and compiled with `ml64.exe`. However, in my case, I am strictly using `as` with `ld` and so I needed to find this function through a complicated procedure using `PEB`.

Comment: `gcc` works by invoking `cc1`, `as`, and `ld` in that order, and it can link code that uses DLLs normally.   Maybe have a look at the asm generated for a C file that calls `fopen`, and the `ld` command GCC uses when you run `gcc -v  foo.c -lsome_library`.

Comment: `fopen` is found on 64-bit and 32-bit code. I just compiled and wrote a file to disk. no underscores. so if maybe down underneath the rocks somewhere it ends up as `_fopen` before it assembles to machine code, you might be right but for the purposes of finding  the function, `_fopen` did not work but `fopen` did

Comment: i'll have to dig deeper to really see what you are talking about. however, as stated, if i searched through `ucrtbase.dll` for `_fopen`, i wouldn't have found it. that's the message I am conveying here